Duda en truncamiento en C++
quería saber porqué el resultado de la división de los dos enteros 'i' y 'j' cuando se asigna a la variable 'm' que es de tipo doble, porqué se trunca dando como resultado '3' y no '3.5', ya que tenía entendido que el compilador de C++ convertía el tipo de menor precisión al tipo de mayor precisión. Espero que me puedan aclarar está duda, gracias.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double m = 0;
   int i = 7, j = 2;
   m =  i / j; 
   cout << m;

   return 0;
}


La precision de la operación, las posibles conversiones implícitas y el tipo del resultado dependen de los operandos, en tu caso ambos son enteros y el resultado es un entero, es posteriormente cuando implicitamente este entero se convierte en double.

Ten en cuenta el orden de evaluación de la expresión siempre, no solo en cuanto a la asignación como en el caso que planteas,  por ejemplo, observa el resultado de   double(j) * i / j;  vs  double(j) * (i / j);

Es un problema frecuente. El compilador solo realiza las conversiones cuando es necesario. Ambos números son enteros así que ocurre una división de enteros (resultando 3) y el cociente es convertido a double.

Ya en el 2017 hicieron una pregunta sobre eso c++ Problema al Dividir 2/3

Muchas gracias por la información.

i / j es una division entre dos enteros (int)ahora el resultado de 7 / 2 es 3 porque C++ realiza la division entera y descarta el residuo (que seria 1) sin importar que luego lo vayas a asignar a una variable de tipo double.. entonces la expresión m = i / j; asigna el valor 3 para m, no 3.5, porque la division entera ya se hizo antes de la asignacion.. si quieres que la division retenga la parte fraccionaria necesitas asegurarte de que al menos uno de los operandos sea de tipo double o float antes de realizar la division, puedes solucionarlo con un cast:
m = static_cast<double>(i) / j;

una forma simpple puedes optar por: m = (double)i / j;
aqui la i se convierte a double antes de la division y lo que sucede es que la operacion se realice en el dominio de los numeros de punto flotante, y el resultado sera 3.5... quiza sea un poco rebuscado explicandolo pero en conclusion te daria algo asi:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double m = 0;
   int i = 7, j = 2;
   m =  static_cast<double>(i) / j; 
   cout << m;

   return 0;
}


Muchas gracias por aclararmelo.

Además del static_cast, antes de iniciar la división se puede hacer una conversión implícita en una de las variables multiplicándola por 1.0 o  1.0f :
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   float m = 0;
   int i = 7, j = 2;
     m = i / (j * 1.0f);
   cout << m;

   return 0;
}

La variable i de tipo int realiza la división de un float, y el tipo int se convierte implícitamente en float.
La variable j es de tipo int. El valor que se pasa 1.0f es de otro tipo, float.
Al multiplicar un int con un float, el tipo entero (int) se convierte implícitamente en float.
El resultado es correcto porque el orden de las operaciones en C++ sigue las mismas reglas que en matemáticas:

Paréntesis ()
Multiplicación, División,  Módulo *, /, %
Adición, Sustracción +, -

Primero se resuelve lo que está dentro de los paréntesis, luego la multiplicación, y por último se realiza la división. En esta lógica, se convierte a float antes de la división, por lo que el resultado será un float.
La conversión puede ser 1.0 o 1.0f.
1.0 = double
1.0f = float

Esta forma es un proceso de promoción de tipo que consiste en modificar el comportamiento de la operación.
